# Using Slick 3.0 with existing DataSource where auto-commit is false

Tags: mysql, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick within an existing Spring app and I pass in the DataSource from the rest of the app with `Database.forDataSource(ds)`. The connection pool in the data source is configured with auto-commit = false and I can't figure out how to get Slick 3.0 to send a commit to MySQL.

I'm just upgrading from 2.0 -> 3.0 and I used to use `session.withTransaction` to have Slick send a commit even on a single update, but even using `.transactionally` doesn't seem to do the trick now. It also doesn't seem like the right thing for a single statement?

How should I integrate the current pool with Slick? Or should I be making a new pool?

One thing that seems to work is wrapping the data source with a proxy and setting the data source there:

```
final LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy result =
  new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(newDataSource());
result.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
```

However, I then get 2 auto commits with all my queries once the connection has been used once:

```
SET autocommit=0
SET autocommit=1
```

This works for now but doesn't seem ideal due to extra statements. Please let me know the best way to proceed and if I can tell Slick to issue a commit. I'm a Slick novice.